# How do I dynamically read from a file using PHP as new information is written into it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a code set up where I use JS and PHP to write to a file and display the output to a html element (in this case a textarea). I have a huge problem about how to go about this. I know that PHP is executed before anything else happens. I use php to echo the file content using my own javascript function

```
output(string) // this outputs whatever into the html element text area
```

PHP:

```
<?php echo "output('".$someText."');"; ?>
```

Now my problem comes around when I update and add contents to that file, but the php has already been executed and trying to read from the file again, will only display results from the last time it executed the php. The only way around this is to refresh the page, thus 'rebuilding' the html content of the file.

This whole code of mine mimics the look and feel of a command line ( you have an output screen with an input box) How can i dynamically display the contents of a file as new content is being added to the file without having to refresh the window. Refreshing the window will work, but not at all what i need for this to work. Any help with this?

For more information about how my code is structured, below you will find a snippet of how the code executes:

```
// main.php
<?php
    // displays the file into the output box
    function displayFile($fileName){
        $file_handler = fopen($fileName, "r");
        while (!feof($file_handler)){
            $line = fgets($file_handler);
            $line = formatFileLine($line);
            echo "output('".$line."');";
        }

        fclose($file_handler);
    }
?>

switch(splitCmd[1]){
    case 'permitted':
        output('\nWells that have been permitted:\n');
        <?php displayFile('permitted.txt'); ?> //calls the php function to display content.
        break;
    case 'drilled':
        output('\nWells that have been drilled:\n');
        <?php displayFile('drilled.txt'); ?>
        break;
    default:
        output('Wrong syntax: show <permitted, drilled>');
}
```

Comment: You will need a client-server Ajax call to retrieve fresh server data on a regular basis.

Comment: Try to load file content via AJAX and use `setInterval` function to reload file in the time you want

Comment: can you guys please write a quick template of how to do that? I can write ajax for php to read javascript variables, but I am not sure how to do it the other way around. The ajax documentation is pretty confusing to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an AJAX request, there are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest is with jQuery (opinion based ofcourse!), here is a link to the documentation. [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Example:

```
function ajaxCall(){

$.ajax({ url: 'PHPFILE.php',
        success: function(e){

            //e is what you get returned from the php file
            $('#div').html(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Oh, and you should ofcourse have the jquery library linked. which you do this way:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so in that function (e) i would put the html element id of my textarea, in the PHPFILE.php is where i would read the file?

Comment: no, you call this function when you want to dynamically refresh your page, with $('#div') you can select an html object by ID, easiest to use a <div id="div"> (# stands for ID), in url it says what page to request, so your php file goes there. everytime you call this function will then refresh your page, understand?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an AJAX call to your PHP file.  Take the output from the PHP script, and embed this into, say, a given div on your page.

Let's pretend you have a div set aside for display.  Let's give you a button to refresh it whenever.

```
<div id="resultdiv"></div>
<input type = "button" id="rbutton" value="Click to Refresh">
```

Style it any way that you please.

Now, let's set up an AJAX call to load the results from the PHP.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {  //document ready psuedonym

       function refreshdata(){

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_data_script.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {myparam1: 'abc', myparam2: '123'},  //these are optional parameters in case your PHP script needs them

    success: function(data){
        $('#resultdiv').html(data);
        },

        error: function(){
        },

        complete: function(){
        }
    }); //end ajax  

       }  //end function 

    $("#rbutton").click(function() {  //clicking the button refreshes the data on demand
        refreshdata();
    });

       refreshdata();  //this will run the function when the page loads


    });//end document ready pseudonym
</script>
```